# Bubble sort in Python using list of lists not ordering correctly

Tags: python, list, sorting, bubble-sort

A bubble sort algorithm in my python program doesn't seem to be finishing the sort or sorting in the correct order.

```
def sort():
    listsImport()
    for passnum in range(len(numberLists)-1, 0, -1):
        for i in range(passnum):
            if numberLists[i][1] > numberLists[i+1][1]:
                temp = numberLists[i]
                numberLists[i] = numberLists[i+1]
                numberLists[i+1] = temp
    print(numberLists)
```

Number lists looks like this:
[['hello','5','1'], ['goodbye', '12', '8'], ['salutations', '14,'9']................... ]
It should be sorting by the second elements in the lists.
Thanks !

Comment: Could you give us an example of "Not correct"? What is your input and your output, then your expected output?

Comment: If your input has strings in the second element, they might not sort how you expect.

Comment: convert `str` value to `int`.. `if int(numberLists[i][1]) > int(numberLists[i+1][1]):`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cast the values to integers:

```
def sort():
  numberLists = [['hello','5','1'], ['goodbye', '12', '8'], ['salutations', '14','9']]
  for passnum in range(len(numberLists)-1, 0, -1):
     for i in range(passnum):
        if int(numberLists[i][1]) > int(numberLists[i+1][1]):
            temp = numberLists[i]
            numberLists[i] = numberLists[i+1]
            numberLists[i+1] = temp
  return numberLists
```

Output:

```
[['hello', '5', '1'], ['goodbye', '12', '8'], ['salutations', '14', '9']]
```